# Is `graphite` R package useful only on Human data?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some enrichment analysis with [R graphite package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graphite.html), on some RNA-Seq data.

In particular I use the *SPIA functions* as illustrated in reported examples!

Using Human data it works fine, but when I enrich for mouse (or other species) the results are always empty!

I suppose that the package is developed only for human pathways, but there are no references to that in the articles.

I tried to contact the developer team, but obtaining no answer... Someone else knows something about this package?

Thanks!

Here I report some code:

```
prepareSPIA(db = pathway.db, pathwaySetName = pathsetname)
p <- runSPIA(de=fc.vector, all=all.genes.names, pathwaySetName =  pathsetname)
```

where *pathway.db* is "kegg", *pathsetname* is a user defined string, *fc.vector* is a vector of log fold changes and *all.genes.names* is the list of gene population.

Comment: this might get more informed answers on a Bioconductor mailing list somewhere ...

Comment: The documentation currently says: "All provided pathways are annotated in human and, since version 1.14, other 13 species are
available." I've been unable to find an archive site that would allow me to tell when that version was current.